# avoid duplicate in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, duplicates

I tried to check some similar post about this, but I didn't find a proper solution to this, I have the following code

```
    if(dgvOC.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        dgvOC.Rows.Add(txtProd.Text, numCant.Value, txtTipo.Text, precioGuardado, precioGuardado * (int)numCant.Value);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= dgvOC.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (txtProd.Text == dgvOC.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usted ya ha agregado un producto con el mismo nombre" +
            ", modifique la cantidad o borre el producto para agregarlo" +
            " de nuevo.", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtProd.Clear();
            txtTipo.Clear();
            numCant.Value = 0;
            return;
        }
        dgvOC.Rows.Add(txtProd.Text, numCant.Value, txtTipo.Text, precioGuardado, precioGuardado * (int)numCant.Value);
    }
```

First If is at the start I don't need to compare it to nothing because there is nothing to compare it with so I just add it (My DGV has "AddingRows" property to false)

I use the for to run on all the DGV, then in the 2nd If what I would like to do is compare the textbox to each row that is in the DGV and if it matches a MessageBox will pop out saying that you've added a product with the same name, then it clears some TextBoxes and a numericupdown, then it returns and if it doesn't match the row adds

...my problem is, using this code the first insert into the DGV works fine, but at the second it displays the warning (even if I add a name that doesn't match with the product) and in the 3rd one it adds a row in blank

Thanks for the help

Comment: Remove the first `If` statement. This question is actually very difficult to understand. Maybe just tell us what you want rather than discuss whats wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry haha, what I would like is to avoid any duplicate regarding the first column in the DGV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this
Create a method to verify content of datagridview  and if there are rows in.

```
       // Call this in your event.
     If(NoRowOrNoDuplicate())
   {   
    dgvOC.Rows.Add(txtProd.Text, numCant.Value, txtTipo.Text, precioGuardado, precioGuardado * (int)numCant.Value);
       }


  //The method be like
    private bool NoRowOrNoDuplicate()
            {
             // Add condition s here
           for (int i = 0; i <= dgvOC.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                    if (txtProd.Text == dgvOC.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                      {
        MessageBox.Show("Usted ya ha agregado un producto con el mismo nombre" +
        ", modifique la cantidad o borre el producto para agregarlo" +
        " de nuevo.", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                   txtProd.Clear();
                   txtTipo.Clear();
                   numCant.Value = 0;
                   return false;
                    }
                   }
            Return true;
             }
```